# How to loop through a txt file to find various strings and do counts in Batch scripting

Tags: batch-file

I have a text file and I would like to create a batch script to search through each line to find a string such as names of fruits i.e. `oranges` in this case and once found do a count of `PASS` and `FAIL`, then resume to the next string and do another count of `PASS` and `FAIL`.....right to the end of the file.  I want to output this string along with the count to a output file.  So the input file will be:

```
Some words
Some words
First string called Oranges
Some words
This line contains PASS
This line contains FAIL
This line contains PASS
This line contains FAIL
Some words
Second string called Apples
Some words
This line contains PASS
This line contains FAIL
This line contains FAIL
This line contains FAIL
```

So the output file would contain

```
Oranges, PASS COUNT 2, FAIL COUNT 2
Apples, PASS COUNT 1, FAIL COUNT 3
```

My only effort of this is a search for strings but I don't know how to do conditions and counts in batch scripting i.e. if Oranges found do a count

```
set findtext1="PASS:"
set findtext2="FAIL:"
set findfile="input.txt"

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr %findtext1% %findfile%') do echo The full line of the string is %%a >> output.txt
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr %findtext2% %findfile%') do echo The full line of the string is %%a >> output.txt
```

Comment: Is the keyword of the group name IE: orange / Apple Always the last word in the line, and do no other lines contain that keyword?

Comment: Always Orange, then Apple.....for now

Comment: You should provide a real-world example since your random text does not match your code. Nevertheless, this site is not a free code/script writing service, neither is it a tutorial or research service, so you are expected to write your own serious attempt to solve the outlined task; when stuck, come back here, [edit] your post and add a [mcve] of your coding attempts! Also please take the [tour], visit the [help] and learn [ask] here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this type of task you need to flag the primary search term as having been encountered before testing the secondary search term. Each time a new primary term is flagged, the old primary term needs to have it's true state removed. Variables are used to flag states in this way.

An example based on your example input and expected output

- Note: The bellow example is not designed for Primary search terms that contain spaces, operators or poison characters - It is **only an example of the logic required for flagging a term as having been encountered**, and will only work for basic search terms such as those provided in the question.

```bat
@Echo off
 Setlocal
 Set PrimarySearchterms="apples" "oranges"
 Set SecondarySearchterms="Pass" "Fail"

 For /f "delims=" %%G in (input.txt)Do For %%T in (%PrimarySearchterms%) Do (
  Echo("%%~G"|%__APPDIR__%Findstr.exe /lic:"%%~T" > nul && Call:SetLast "%%~T"
  If defined $%%~T (
   For %%V in (%Secondarysearchterms%)Do Echo("%%~G"|%__APPDIR__%Findstr.exe /lic:"%%~V" >nul && Set /A $%%~T[%%~V]+=1+0
  )
 )
 If defined Str Set "$%Str%="
 Set $
 Endlocal
Goto:Eof

:SetLast
 Rem assigns true state to current primary searchterm.
 Rem removes definition of the last primary searchterm.

 If defined Str Set "$%Str%="
 Set "str=%~1"
 Set "$%Str%=true"
```

Outputs:

```
$apples[Fail]=3
$apples[Pass]=1
$oranges[Fail]=2
$oranges[Pass]=2
```